# How to get Moodle user id through Web Services API using token

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

#### Some background

I am connecting external application (server) with Moodle through Web Services API.

- First a user obtains web services token through a call to `/login/token.php`.
- Above token can be used to call web services functions through `/webservice/rest/server.php` endpoint.

#### The problem

In some cases I need to provide `userid`, which I don't know, because `/login/token.php` does not return it.

#### Things I've tried

I searched through the Web Services api documentation and found `core_session_time_remaining` function. Documentation says it returns `userid` and `timeremaining` properties:

```
object {
userid int   //The current user id.
timeremaining int   //The number of seconds remaining in this session.
}
```

The problem is, returned `userid` is always `0`, irrelevant of what `token` was used to call this function. Is it a bug in Moodle, or am I using it wrong? How can I get `userid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you ever tried using the `core_webservice_get_site_info` wsfunction?

I use it and works fine.

According to the docs: "Return some site info / user info / list web service functions" [API Doc](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions)

Comment: This function seems to work correctly, thanks.